# Stored procedure and function returning unexpected results

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using stored procedure output for a parameter of a function

```
DECLARE @SeqNo int; 
DECLARE @CharNumber varchar(10);
EXEC  dbo.sp_GetNextCounter 'ITEMTYPE', @SeqNo OUTPUT;
EXEC @CharNumber=dbo.rf_f_CIntToChar @SeqNo, 6;
SELECT @CharNumber;
```

---

The stored procedure `sp_GetNextCounter` has an integer output called `SeqNo`.

The stored procedure:

```
@param0 varchar(12),
@SeqNo INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
IF (@param0 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    set nocount on
    DECLARE @reqseqno INT
    SELECT @reqseqno = CounterValue FROM Counters WHERE CounterName = @param0
    UPDATE Counters SET CounterValue = @reqseqno + 1 WHERE CounterName = @param0
    SELECT @reqseqno AS 'SeqNo'
END
END
GO
```

---

The function `dbo.rf_f_CIntToChar` takes two parameters (integer to convert, number of characters to return) returns a `varchar` version of the integer with leading zeros.

The function:

```
(@intVal int, @intLen int)
RETURNS varchar(10)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
IF @intlen > 20 SET @intlen = 20
IF @intlen < LEN(@intVal) RETURN RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), @intVal), @intlen)
RETURN REPLICATE('0', @intLen - LEN(@intVal)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), @intVal)
END
GO
```

Both the stored procedure and the function operate as they should when used separately.

Why does the above query return `SeqNo` rather than `CharNumber`?

Comment: Can you add a simplified version of the source for that SP and function?

Comment: Please post example code for the sp and function that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stored procedure never assigns a value to the output parameter `@SeqNo`

Comment: Bingo. Thanks.. I don't know how I missed that.